# Bond value as a function of spread change and duration/maturity

Tags: fixed-income, credit-risk, valuation, duration

I am trying to calculate the change of value in a universe of bonds given a series of shocks to the credit spread of each bond. As a constraint, the initial dataset only contains the spread change for each individual bond and its duration/maturity.

Is there any simple way to approximate the change in value for each bond given this parameter set?

PS: I can also retrieve the initial bond price or other fields, but due to the size/heterogeneity of the portfolio this will substantially reduce the number of bonds with available data. Similarly, due to size/heterogeneity, I am looking for an approximate formula instead of a full revaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to re-use the rate duration as a measure of spread sensitivity as well:

Let's assume a simple vanilla fixed-coupon-bearing bond w/o embedded optionalities that pays at coupon rate $c$ annually. Let's further assume a continuously compounded flat risk-free zero rate curve $r$ and a continuously compounded flat spread zero curve $s$. In this setting, assuming today $t_0=0$, today's present value of a risky cashflow at time $t$ equals

$$D(r,s,t)=e^{-(r+s)t}$$

The present value formula for the vanilla bond is a portfolio of discounted cash flows. As $r$ and $s$ are added in the discount factor formula, the derivatives (or sensitivity) of the term with respect to one or the other are identical.

Thus, in practice, for fixed-coupon bonds, you can re-use duration up to some interpolation issues for calculating the effect of a spread widening:

$$
PV(r,s+\epsilon)-PV(r,s)\approx\frac{\partial PV}{\partial s}\times\epsilon\approx\frac{\partial PV}{\partial r}\times\epsilon=\mathrm{Duration}\times\epsilon
$$

where the first $\approx$ stems from the Taylor approximation and the second  $\approx$ allows for the fact that the two derivatives are not exactly identical in practice, e.g. due to differences in curve interpolation mechanisms, different curve pillars or the like.

HTH?

Comment: Thank you @Kermittfrog. This helps a lot (both the logic and the underlying explanation)

Comment: As a related question, is there any way to approximate a measure equivalent to the “duration” from the maturity of a floating-rate bond? (so that the “duration” approach can be applied to floating bonds).

Comment: I guess the last question is akin to asking how I can erive the (credit) spread duration for the FRNs in my dataset. ¿Is this right?

Comment: Hoping that you are solely looking for rough-n-ready figures: Why not simply multiply by the time-to-maturity? Furthermore, you could check what kind of duration you have: If duration for your FRN is close to maturity, you have the discounting PV01 - you may "simply" re-use that...